# Pyspark LabeledPoint Error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I've been working on a classification problem with pyspark, and have created a RDD and map, but when I attempt to add LabeledPoint I get the error

```
 Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
```

Here's the code and output below:

```
 %pyspark
 from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint

 features = df.map(lambda row: row[0:15])
 print features.take(1)
 [(u'12.95', u'AOL.COM', u'3', u'1', u'-4276', u'7', u'0', u'1', u'1', u'1', u'0', u'1', u'0', u'0', u'1')]

 lab = df.map(lambda row: row[16])
 print lab.take(1)
 [u'0']

 transformedData = lab.zip(features)
 print transformedData.take(2)
 [(u'0', (u'12.95', u'AOL.COM', u'3', u'1', u'-4276', u'7', u'0', u'1', u'1', u'1', u'0', u'1', u'0', u'0', u'1')), (u'0', (u'11.01', u'AOL.COM', u'3', u'1', u'-4276', u'7', u'0', u'1', u'1', u'1', u'0', u'1', u'0', u'0', u'1'))]

 transformedData = transformedData.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row[0],[row[1]]))
 print transformedData.take(2)
 Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
```

Answer (score 0):

Second argument is a numeric vector or list not a list of strings:

> Parameters:
>
> - label – Label for this data point.
> - features – Vector of features for this point (NumPy array, list, pyspark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector, or scipy.sparse column matrix).